# In python, when we iterate through a list, is it creating an iterator object?

Tags: python-3.x

Is a for loop actually implemented like this:

```
iter_obj = iter(iterable)

# infinite loop
while True:
    try:
        # get the next item
        element = next(iter_obj)
        # do something with element
    except StopIteration:
        # if StopIteration is raised, break from loop
        break
```

Not really right? Like other exceptions seem to be ignored here without StopIteration. is for a method?

How is this actually implemented?

```
for element in my_list:
    print(element)
```

Is for taking an argument called element? What is in? What is going on under the hood?

Answer (score 0):

Aside from `iter_obj` existing solely in an unnamed location on the stack, and the `try` block being scoped solely to the `next`, not to whatever is done with the result as well, and all the code involved being implemented with dedicated opcodes that do the work more efficiently in C, you got it, that's how it's implemented. Fixing the `try` block scope issue, it would look like:

```
iter_obj = iter(iterable)

# infinite loop
while True:
    try:
        # get the next item
        element = next(iter_obj)
    except StopIteration:
        # if StopIteration is raised, break from loop
        break
    # do something with element that won't catch StopIteration for you
```

The main efficiency gained in the real implementation is that it has a dedicated opcode (`FOR_ITER` at time of writing) for extracting the next item from the iterator and checking for `StopIteration` without invoking the actual (expensive) exception raising/handling machinery. That's not something you can do at the Python layer, but it's a design feature of the CPython interpreter that makes the `for` loop perform well. The closest you could get to what it's doing at the Python layer would be something like:

```
NULL = object()  # We don't have real NULL from C, but we can simulate it as a guaranteed unique object
iter_obj = iter(iterable)
while (element := next(iter_obj, NULL)) is not NULL:
    # do something with element
```

This second iteration is slightly more accurate, in that it will continue to function as an equivalent implementation in the presence of a `else` block attached to the `for` loop (which only triggers if the `for` loop ends "naturally", rather than via `break`), since it will similarly end the loop naturally rather than via a `break`.

Answer (score -1):

In these cases, the `dis` (built-in) library comes in handy. It shows the underlying bytecode. Let's see what it says:

```py
In [1]: import dis

In [2]: dis.dis("x = [1, 2, 3]\nfor r in x:\n\tprint(r)")
  0           0 RESUME                   0

  1           2 BUILD_LIST               0
              4 LOAD_CONST               0 ((1, 2, 3))
              6 LIST_EXTEND              1
              8 STORE_NAME               0 (x)

  2          10 LOAD_NAME                0 (x)
             12 GET_ITER
        >>   14 FOR_ITER                13 (to 42)
             16 STORE_NAME               1 (r)

  3          18 PUSH_NULL
             20 LOAD_NAME                2 (print)
             22 LOAD_NAME                1 (r)
             24 PRECALL                  1
             28 CALL                     1
             38 POP_TOP
             40 JUMP_BACKWARD           14 (to 14)

  2     >>   42 LOAD_CONST               1 (None)
             44 RETURN_VALUE
```

As you can see on byte 12 - 14 (line 2), ~~no it does not explicitly create a new iterator (i.e. it does not take extra memory)~~ yes it creates a new iterator via the `GET_ITER`, then calls the built-in bytecode `FOR_ITER`.

However, a question still remains: How is the instruction `FOR_ITER` interpreted? Take `CPython` for example, we can see in the source that there are [constants](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/6888cccac0776d965cc38a7240e1bdbacb952b91/Lib/_opcode_metadata.py#L79) which specify different codepaths for different object types. So for example, if you are iterating through a list object, the `FOR_ITER_LIST` implementation will be called, which I assume will directly access the list in memory.

Comment: You missed the `GET_ITER`, which is in fact equivalent to calling `iter()` on the object and storing it on the stack. It doesn't take *much* extra memory (the iterator is a live view of the underlying `list`, it doesn't copy the contents), but it is creating a new iterator.

Comment: Thanks for the edit and clarification, I have added more explanation

Comment: On the `FOR_ITER_LIST` thing, a note: The specializing adaptive bytecode is very new (some added in 3.11, more in 3.12); there was no special handling for `list`s before that point.